# jquery animation is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Check my piece of code here 
http://jsfiddle.net/metalshan/eHG6X/
What I want is, 
If I click on the green bar in the left side, its width should toggle to 10% and 20%. While doing that, the right side should also toggle its width. Here, the left portion is working nice, but when I ran animate function for the "#content",

```
    $("#content").animate({
        width: '90%'
    })
```

it's showing the #content animating, not the divs inside it.
If you see the code in jsFiddle u will understand.

Comment: In your fiddle the blue bars on the right are expanding. What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: All the divs are shown perfectly in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `absolute positioning` instead of floating and the problem is solved.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHG6X/6/)

```
#container{
    overflow: hidden;
}    
#lower{
    position: relative;
}
#nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

An even better option would be to use an `absolutely positioned table`, and then you can animate only one pane instead of both of them.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHG6X/10/)

**CSS:**

```
html,body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#lower{
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: table;
}
#nav{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width:20%;
}
#content{
    display: table-cell;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#nav").click(function(){
    if (isSmall) $(this).animate({ width:'20%' })
    else         $(this).animate({ width:'10%' })

    isSmall=!isSmall;
});
```

Comment: Thanks... that's exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Change it to

```
$("#content").animate({ width: '90%'}, 100)
```